# Print out the amount of times 2 words appear in the syslog. But also have it tell me how many times for each hour

Tags: bash, scripts

So I'm trying to create a bash script that looks for two words in my syslog file. 
Then I want the script to print out how many times those two words have appeared.
Also I want it to print it out for every hour of the day.
So like if the word dog appeared 4 times during the first hour of today, it says Hour one, dog 4.
Finally at the end of the script I want it to print out how many times those words appeared all day.

The sudo code I have thus far is

```
if 2 > hour
find permit
find block
print both
finish

if 1 < hour < 2
find permit
find block
print both
finish

if 2 < hour < 3
find permit
find block
print both
finish
```

command is
    grep -o "\WORD\" Syslog.txt * | sort | uniq -c

Answer (score 1):

Here is some less-pseudo code. I have not tested it so it may not work at all, but it's where I might start.

```
function findprint {
    local word1 = $(echo $1 | grep -o "\WORD1\" | wc -w)
    local word2 = $(echo $1 | grep -o "\WORD2\" | wc -w)
    word1total=$[word1total+word1]
    word2total=$[word2total+word2]
    echo "$word1 WORD1"
    echo "$word2 WORD2"
}
word1total = 0;
word2total = 0;
while read line; do
    if [ hour -lt 2 ]; then
        echo "Hour 1"
        findprint "$line"
    fi

    if [ hour -gt 1 && hour -lt 2 ]; then
        echo "Hour 2"
        findprint "$line"
    fi

    if [ hour -gt 2 && hour -lt 3 ]; then
        echo "Hour 3"
        findprint "$line"
    fi
done < /var/log/syslog

echo "TOTAL:"
echo "$word1total WORD1"
echo "$word2total WORD2"
```

Comment: Getting a syntax error at the second to last line. "Unexpected EOF while looking for matching `'" Will continue to figure it out of course.